# SetupPOS cannot find or load main class com.epson.pos.SetupPOS.SetupPOS in Linux Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: ubuntu, javapos, pos

I Installed JavaPOS v1.14.5 in my Ubuntu Linux. But when I run the SetupPOS, it gives me an error:

```
 cannot find or load main class com.epson.pos.SetupPOS.SetupPOS
```

I'm really not sure why this is happening.

This is my command:

```
/opt/EpsonJavaPO/SetupPOS$ ./SetupPOS
```

I tried using lower version(1.14.4) but it gives the same error.

What did I miss? Is this a bug?
Thanks

Comment: I'm using oracle-java8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a bug.

```
V. 1.14.5 JavaPOSInstall.sh Bug
V. 1.14.4 Bug SetupPOS
V. 1.14.3 Bug SetupPOS
V. 1.14.2 Bug SetupPOS
V. 1.14.1 Bug SetupPOS
```

Fixed in [Ver.1.14.6L](https://download.epson-biz.com/modules/pos/index.php?page=single_soft&cid=5667&scat=40&pcat=3)